# Qt widget operations appear after slot function ends

Tags: qt

I'm a newbie in Qt and the following problem is driving me crazy. I suppose there is an easy solution for this but so far I wasn't successful with google etc.

I have a finished console application and my goal is to add a gui to this application. I'm using VS2010 Ultimate and have included the Qt add in. Then I created a Qt project and included a second project including my application. The structure looks like this:

main.cpp:

```
#include "PROJECT_gui.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include <PROJECT.hpp>

using namespace PROJECT;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  PROJECT_GUI w;
  w.show();
  w.setup(argc, argv);
  return a.exec();
}
```

PROJECT_gui.hpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_PROJECT_gui.h"
#include <PROJECT.hpp>

using namespace PROJECT;


class PROJECT_GUI : public QMainWindow {
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   PROJECT_GUI(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
   ~PROJECT_GUI();
   void setup(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   PROJECTEngine_->setGui(ui);
   PROJECTEngine_->setup(argc, argv);}

   Ui::PROJECT_GUIClass ui;

private:
   boost::shared_ptr<PROJECTengine> PROJECTEngine_; 
};
```

PROJECT.hpp:

```
#include <QtCore/qobject.h>
#include "ui_PROJECT_gui.h"

namespace PROJECT {
class PROJECTengine : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   PROJECTengine();

#ifdef _Qt      
   // Gui functions
   void setGui(Ui::PROJECT_GUIClass& ui){
      ui_ = boost::shared_ptr<Ui::PROJECT_GUIClass>(&ui);
   }

   void guiOut(QString text){
      ui_->textBrowserOutput->append(text);
   }
#endif
public slots:
   void createScenarios();

private:
#ifdef _Qt
   // GUI Objects
   QString outputText_;
   boost::shared_ptr<Ui::PROJECT_GUIClass> ui_;
#endif
};
```

The slot createScenarios is connected to a push buttom signal:

```
QObject::connect(ui.toolButtonSzenarienBerechnen, SIGNAL(clicked()),  &*PROJECTEngine_, SLOT(createScenarios()));
```

The method createScenarios() looks somehow like this:

```
void PROJECTengine::createScenarios(){
   Step1: some code doing a lot of time consuming stuff
#ifdef _Qt
   guiOut("Step 1 ready!");
#endif
  Step2: some code doing a lot of time consuming stuff
#ifdef _Qt
   guiOut("Step 2 ready!");
#endif
  Step3: some code doing a lot of time consuming stuff
#ifdef _Qt
   guiOut("Step 3 ready!");
#endif
}
```

All of this seems to work somehow. If I push the button createScenarios() is invoked. All time consuming code parts are done and also the gui output works, but the timing is my problem. What I want to have is that after completing Step i the text "Step i ready!" is displayed in my gui. But this does not happen. Instead all steps are executed and at the very end the three outputs:
Step 1 ready
Step 2 ready
Step 3 ready
are displayed in my gui at once.

I'm totally helpless in the moment and tried several things. In a first trial I didn't include a reference of my Ui::PROJECT_GUIClass to the PROJECTengine class. Instead I had a signal "output" in the PROJECTenginge class:

```
signals:
   void output(QString);
```

and connected this to the append method of my textbrowser widget:

```
QObject::connect(&*PROJECTEngine_, SIGNAL(output(QString)), ui.textBrowserOutput, SLOT(append(QString)));
```

Instead of calling guiOut I throw an output signal in the createscenarios() method. No idea if one of these ways is preferable? But the result was the same as above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call [QApplication::processEvents();](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) after each step.
You have this behavior because each call of `ui.textBrowserOutput->append()` (doesn't matter directly or by emitting signal) is putting into the message queue and return the control to your function. When you leave it Qt starts to execute each message in queue. `QApplication::processEvents();` tells to Qt to do it right now, but not when your function will end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid calling `processEvents`, you can also stage out your actions by emitting a signal for each of the 3 steps in your button clicked slot. You can use `Qt::QueuedConnection` when you connect these signals to 3 different slots. Each of these slots would execute one of your steps AFTER the button slot has exited. Call your `guiOut` in each of the slots. The net result of this is your button clicked slot queues 3 subsequent events that are processed in the order they were emitted.